# Java - While loop in runnable jar is not iterating but the same code working fine in eclipse

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I exported a swing program to a runnable jar from Eclipse with "Package required libraries into generated JAR" option. The same code works fine in Eclipse but when I try run the .Jar file, the while loop in code is not iterating. It keep executing the code with same value infinitely.

```
private Set<String> `pagesVisited` = new HashSet<String>();
private List<String> pagesToBeVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
int depth = 5;
String url = "www.example.com";
while(this.pagesVisited.size() < depth)
            {

                if(this.pagesToBeVisit.isEmpty())
                {
                    currentUrl = url;
                    this.pagesVisited.add(url);
                }
                else
                {
                    currentUrl = this.nextUrl();
                }
                pm.crawl(currentUrl); 

                boolean success = pm.searchForServer(currentUrl);

                }

                if(success)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sucess");
                }
                this.pagesToBeVisit.addAll(pm.getLinks());

            }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to check if there is anything wrong with it?

Comment: @ArnauLacambra Just have a look the code

Comment: If pages to be visited is empty (which it is initially i guess) the variable `currentUrl` is set to `url` but don't see where `url` is initialized.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You only add an url to the `pagesVisited` array, when `pagesToBeVisit` is empty, an after the first iteration, it seems that it will never be emtpy again. Could be there your error?